# Trouble integrating Venmo iOS SDK Pod

Tags: parse-platform, cocoapods, venmo

I have been following the ReadMe from the [Venmo iOS SDK](https://github.com/venmo/venmo-ios-sdk) but am having issues even importing the pod. When I try importing the SDK and running the application, I receive the following error:

[image: error 1]

The SDK mentions that there can be issues with a project that uses Parse (mine does), so I added [these other linker flags](https://gist.github.com/diogeneshamilton/6c1585280da8de16560d). Upon doing so, I receive this error:

[image]

Anyone else run into similar issues with this SDK or have any idea how to at least allow my project to import the SDK? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download VenmoAppSwitch.framework at https://github.com/venmo/app-switch-ios-framework or from a similar developer website from venmo.com

Follow the set up steps and if there are any follow up questions, please let me know.

This is how it was done for our Payments App at https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paynet/id797415713?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I had that and other problems with Venmo IOS SDK, i think you´re duplicating Flags and there´s other you don´t have, try to go to your project -> your target -> Build Settings -> Linking -> Other Linker Flags. And be sure youre not dupicating, in the image show you the linker flags i use for my project.

*Sorry for my english hope you understand

[Other Linker Flags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONRua.png)